# PHPUnit how to test if a method has the correct amount of arguments?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Before start shooting me, just to know that I am totally new on Unit testing, so I don't even know if the question I posting here, is possible to be achieved or not.

So, what I like to do, is to test if the constructor method of a class gets a certain amount of arguments. How can I do that ?

My basic class is the following:

```
class Time {

    public function __construct() {

    }

}
```

and my test is the following:

```
require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/time.php";
require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/vendor/autoload.php";

class TimeTests extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    protected $classInstance;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->classInstance = new Time();
    }

    public function testConstructorExists() {

        $this->assertTrue ( method_exists( $this->classInstance , '__construct' ), 'Constructor method does not exists' );

    }

}
```

Currently the first test works normally, but I don't know how to test the constructor arguments.

For this constructor I like to have three integer arguments, so, how can I right the test for the arguments existence?

One possible solution I am thinking of, is to use the Throw Exception inside the constructor, but again I don't know if this is correct.

Any help please ? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use PHP reflection to do this:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('ReflectionClass');
$constructor = $class->getConstructor();
$numberOfParams = $constructor->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
```

You can check the PHP documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstructor.php
http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getnumberofrequiredparameters.php

Comment: Yes, but is that the phpunit test? It will ensure that the class will have the correct number of arguments in the declaration, and that is worth tetsing for in case of later mods. But it does nothing for the runtime code which should test for argument type and throw an exception when not found. Integrs not being something you can type hint for.

Comment: Indeed, this will only test the correct amount of arguments. But that is what this unit test is supposed to do. If you want to check if the constructor throws an exception when some variable is not the type that it should be, you should write a separate test for that. (just create an instance and check for the exception)

Comment: agreed, that was the question asked. I was just asking if that should be the test in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You test that the constructor arguments are proper by calling them in your tests.  You don't need to specify that a `__construct` method exists or that it takes three arguments (since your example is a Time object, it could take one or two even).

You want to test how you are going to use your class.  You said taking three arguments, so probably hour, minute and second.  Now, you are probably going to have some method to return a string showing the time.  Let's test that:

```
public function testGetTime() {
    $hour = 12;
    $minute = 34;
    $second = 13;

    $time = new Time($hour, $minute, $second);
    $this->assertEquals("$hour:$minute:$second", $time->getTime());
}
```

So in order to pass this test, you have to create a constructor that takes three arguments and create a method to output the time.

Later, I might decide that I want to allow the user to not specify the number of seconds, that is a common practice.  So then I add test like so:

```
public function testGetTimeNoSeconds() {
   $hour = 3;
   $minute = 34;

   $time = new Time($hour, $minute);

   $this->assertEquals("$hour:$minute:00", $time->getTime());
}
```

Oh look, the last constructor argument is now optional!!  You have to update it, no problem.

With this, our constructor gets tested, a lot.  But with this, I don't need to know anything about what the method looks like.  I just need to know what the class is supposed to do.  Constraining the methods like you are looking to do makes your tests less usable and would prevent easy refactoring.

Invalid parameters get easily tested using a handy data provider like so:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider dataInvalidParameters
 */
public function testInvalidParameters($hour, $minute, $second, $message) {
    $this->setExpectedException('InvalidArgument', $message);

    $time = new Time($hour, $minute, $second);
}

public function dateInvalidParameters() {
    return [
        ['a', 12, 23, 'Hour must be an integer'],
        [12, 'b', 23, 'Minute must be an integer'],
        [12, 12, 'c', 'Second must be an integer'],
    ];
}
```

And if you want to specify that the values are in the right range, it is easy to add another test case.